# Can I redefine the iterator variable in the body of a for-loop?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, scope, iterator

Here's a contrived example:

```
from itertools import cycle
def foobar():
    A = [1,2,3,4,5]
    B = [6,7,8,9,10]
    it = cycle(A)
    tmp=0
    for item in it:
        print item, tmp
        if tmp>10:
            it=cycle(B) #is this possible?
        if tmp>30:
            return tmp
        tmp+=item
```

output:

```
1 0
2 1
3 3
4 6
5 10
1 15
2 16
3 18
4 21
5 25
1 30
2 31
```

I'm trying to iterate over one iterable in a for loop until a condition is met, at which point I redefine *it* so that it iterates over another list, using the same loop body.

The code does not function the way I'd like it to in its current form: it continues to use *cycle(A)*, even after I redefined *it=cycle(B)*. I imagine there is some sort of scope issue where the code inside the loop is unable to modify the loop conditions. Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here, or will I need to make duplicate or nested for-loops to iterate over multiple lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the condition on a for loop. You could always use a while and some statement to change the next item of the iterator you want to use, for example:

```
from itertools import cycle

def foobar():
    A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    B = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    tmp = 0
    iter_A = cycle(A)
    iter_B = cycle(B)
    use_A = True
    while True:
        if use_A:
            item = next(iter_A)
        else:
            item = next(iter_B)
        print item, tmp
        if tmp > 10:
            use_A = False
        if tmp > 30:
            return tmp

        tmp += item
```

output:

```
1 0
2 1
3 3
4 6
5 10
1 15
6 16
7 22
8 29
9 37
```

I hope this helps.

**Update:**

As per the comment from Martijn Pieters, the following should also work:

```
from itertools import cycle

def foobar():
    A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    B = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    tmp = 0
    iter_A = cycle(A)
    iter_B = cycle(B)
    it = iter_A
    while True:
        item = next(it)
        print item, tmp
        if tmp > 10:
            it = iter_B
        if tmp > 30:
            return tmp

        tmp += item
```

Comment: Rather than use a flag, just use `it = iter_A`,then later switch to `it = iter_B`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to directly do what you want. The `for` loop in your code only references the initial value of the iterable you pass when it first starts. It calls `iter()` on that iterable and uses the iterator it gets to get the items to iterate over. Rebinding the variable you used in the `for` won't change anything, since that variable is not used by the loop's internal logic after it's got the iterator.

I suspect using `break` and another loop will be the best way to solve this. But if you *really* wanted to keep the loop code as close as possible to what you currently, you could write your own iterator that would let swap from one (internally stored) iterator to another on demand:

```
class swapable_iterator(object):
    def __init__(self, it):
        self.it = it

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return next(self.it)

    __next__ = next # Python 3 compatibility

    def swap(self, new_it):
        self.it = new_it
```

You'll still need to change your loop logic a little bit, since currently it will swap to `cycle(B)` over and over (after `tmp > 10`), only ever seeing the first value.

Try something like:

```
def foobar():
    A = [1,2,3,4,5]
    B = [6,7,8,9,10]
    it = swapable_iterator(cycle(A)) # wrap the cycle with our custom iterator object
    tmp=0
    for item in it:
        print item, tmp
        if item == 5 and tmp > 10: # this will happen exactly once with the A and B above
            it.swap(cycle(B)) # this modifies "it" in place, rather than rebinding it
        if tmp>30:
            return tmp
        tmp+=item
```

Comment: That's very interesting. Would the swapable iterator really work though? If the for loop is using the result of `iter()`, then it seems like if you called `it.swap` would run into the same issues as before, which is that it wouldn't cause the for-loop to re-evaluate the iterator and change the looping conditions. Thanks for the answer

Comment: It is an iterator, so its `__iter__` method returns `self`. The reason you couldn't swap `it` in your original code (which, as a `cycle` was also an iterator who's `__iter__` method returns `self`) was that you were rebinding the name `it`, not modifying the iterator in place. Calling `it.swap` (when `it` is a `swapable_iterator`) will modify it in place, so the loop will pick up the changes as desired.